# Random Walks and Gaussian (Normal) Distribution in R

Tags: r, function, normal-distribution

I'm very new to coding in R(coding in general). I've created a distribution using a random walk within the following code:

```
    set.seed(124)
    norm <- rnorm(1000)
    mean(norm)
    mean(norm)^2
    sd(norm)
    d <- density(norm)
    plot(d)
```

Now I want to create a function of n-steps using the above distribution.  The function calculates the expected values based on the probability of moving n-steps to the left or right from the center.  I have no idea where to begin.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should really have a clear, specific programming question in your post. If you have a question about statistical models like random walks, perhaps your question better belongs on [stats.se]. Otherwise you need to more clearly describe how you want to turn those values from a random normal distribution into steps and directions. It's unclear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each normally distributed variate is your step size (positive moves right and negative moves left), then the cumulative sum of your random draws represents your current position. You can compute that with the `cumsum` function in R:

```
set.seed(144)
pos <- cumsum(rnorm(1000))
plot(seq_along(pos), pos, xlab="Step Number", ylab="Current Position")
```

[image]

Using `replicate` and logical operations, you can simulate any number of different questions about random walks. For instance "with what probability does the value of the random walk exceed 100 within the first 1000 steps" could be simulated with:

```
set.seed(144)
exceed.100 <- replicate(100000, any(cumsum(rnorm(1000)) >= 100))
mean(exceed.100)
# [1] 0.00173
```

From these 100k replicates, it looks like the probability is around 0.17% that the random walk will exceed 100 during the first 1000 steps.